# How to extract number from string in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex

My case is extract number between text (ex: FL-number-$) from string in File names column to Check column. Example:

1. 2022-06-09-FR-Echecks.pdf > Return ''
2. 2022-06-09-FR-FL-3-$797.pdf  > Return 3
3. 2022-06-09-FR-TX-20-$35149.91.pdf > Return 20

My case as below

[image]

This code I used:

`dt_test['File_names_page'] = dt_test['File names'].str.extract('\-([0-99])-\$')`

It only return one digit number as below:

[image]

So how to extract all number (all digit) in my case?

Tks for all attention!

Comment: `[0-99]` = `[0-9]` = `[90-9]` = `[996994992999999999990-999991999999]` - all match just one occurrence of a digit. `[0-9]+` = one or more digits, `[0-9]{2}` - two digits, `[0-9]{1,2}` - one or two digits, `[0-9]{1,3}` - one, two or three digits, etc.

Comment: Tks Wiktor, it work for my case!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a 0-99 range, you should use `\d{1,2}` for one or two digits:

```
dt_test['File_names_page'] = dt_test['File names'].str.extract(r'-(\d{1,2})-\$')
```

Or for any number of digits (at least 1) `\d+`:

```
dt_test['File_names_page'] = dt_test['File names'].str.extract(r'-(\d+)-\$')
```

*NB. `-` doesn't require an escape*

Example:

```
    File names File_names_page
0  ABC-12-$456              12
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern is slightly off.  Just use `\d+` to match any integer number:

```py
dt_test["File_names_page"] = dt_test["File names"].str.extract(r'-(\d+)-\$')
```